# Merging files Using Java

Tags: java

I have two files... arrivals.txt and pickups.txt

File1 :

```
TickeNum,Loc,DayofMonth,Hour

1421,127,12,8 

1422,108,12,8 

1423,110,12,9 

1424,112,12,9

1425,101,12,9 

1426,105,12,9 

1427,106,12,10

1428,109,12,10 

1429,102,12,11 

1430,107,12,12 

1431,122,12,14 

1432,128,12,17 

1433,132,12,19 

1434,136,12,21

1435,141,12,23 

1436,142,13,6
```

and

File 2:

```
TickeNum,DayofMonth,Hour

1422,12,9

1428,12,12

1423,12,13

1429,12,14

1431,12,16

1424,12,17

1421,12,18

1425,12,19

1426,13,21

1434,13,7

1435,13,9

1436,13,16

1430,13,19

1432,13,20
```

TARGET OUTPUT

```
Ticket: 1422, Arrived: 12: 8 --- Pickup: 12: 9 ------ Cost: 7.00

Ticket: 1428, Arrived: 12:10 --- Pickup: 12:12 ------ Cost: 10.00

Ticket: 1423, Arrived: 12: 9 --- Pickup: 12:13 ------ Cost: 15.00

Ticket: 1429, Arrived: 12:11 --- Pickup: 12:14 ------ Cost: 13.00

Ticket: 1431, Arrived: 12:14 --- Pickup: 12:16 ------ Cost: 10.00

Ticket: 1424, Arrived: 12: 9 --- Pickup: 12:17 ------ Cost: 22.00

Ticket: 1421, Arrived: 12: 8 --- Pickup: 12:18 ------ Cost: 22.00

Ticket: 1425, Arrived: 12: 9 --- Pickup: 12:19 ------ Cost: 22.00

Ticket: 1426, Arrived: 12: 9 --- Pickup: 13:21 ------ Cost: 52.00

Ticket: 1434, Arrived: 12:21 --- Pickup: 13: 7 ------ Cost: 35.00

Ticket: 1435, Arrived: 12:23 --- Pickup: 13: 9 ------ Cost: 29.00

Ticket: 1436, Arrived: 13: 6 --- Pickup: 13:16 ------ Cost: 22.00

Ticket: 1430, Arrived: 12:12 --- Pickup: 13:19 ------ Cost: 52.00

Ticket: 1432, Arrived: 12:17 --- Pickup: 13:20 ------ Cost: 48.00
```

Any help is appreciated...

My code as of so far... (that you'll probably need anyway...)

main:

```
public class LotDriver
{
    public static ParkingLot lot1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
       System.out.println("Adam Klein's Parking Lot Revenue Checker - Previously Don Smith's");
       File file1 = new File("arrivals.txt");
       File file2 = new File("pickups.txt");
       lot1 = new ParkingLot(101, 50);
       lot1.readArrivals("arrivals.txt");
       System.out.println("Total Cars parked: " + lot1.getTotalCars());
       lot1.readPickups("pickups.txt");
       lot1.merge(file1, file2);
       lot1.outputCars();
       System.out.println("Total Cars remaining: " + lot1.getTotalCars());
       System.out.printf("\nTotal Revenue: %10.2f\n",lot1.getRevenue());
   }

}`
```

In ANOTHER file... I have this merge method

```
public static void merge(File file1, File file2) throws IOException {

Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(file1);
Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(file2);

while (scanner1.hasNextLine() && scanner2.hasNextLine())
         {
  String trash = scanner1.nextLine();
  String trash2 = scanner2.nextLine();

    String line1 = scanner1.nextLine();
    String line2 = scanner2.nextLine();

    // parse line1
    String[] line1Tokens = line1.split(",");

    // parse line2
    String[] line2Tokens = line2.split(",");

    // Print
    String ticket = line1Tokens[0];
    String arrived1 = line1Tokens[2];
    String arrived2 = line1Tokens[3];

    String pickup1 = line2Tokens[1];
    String pickup2 = line2Tokens[2];

    System.out.println("Ticket: " + ticket + ", " + 
                       "Arrived: " + arrived1 + ":" + arrived2 + " --- " + 
                       "Pickup: " + pickup1 + ":" + pickup2 + " --- " + 
                       "Cost: ");

}
```

}

It throws an error:

```
Ticket: 1421, Arrived: 12:8 --- Pickup: 12:9 --- Cost: 
Ticket: 1423, Arrived: 12:9 --- Pickup: 12:13 --- Cost: 
Ticket: 1425, Arrived: 12:9 --- Pickup: 12:16 --- Cost: 
Ticket: 1427, Arrived: 12:10 --- Pickup: 12:18 --- Cost: 
Ticket: 1429, Arrived: 12:11 --- Pickup: 13:21 --- Cost: 
Ticket: 1431, Arrived: 12:14 --- Pickup: 13:9 --- Cost: 
Ticket: 1433, Arrived: 12:19 --- Pickup: 13:19 --- Cost: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at ParkingLot.merge(ParkingLot.java:65)
at LotDriver.main(LotDriver.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: make an object that represents your files, and load the content from each file into the object, and then regenerate the file

Comment: -1 This is currently just a wall of text with no actual code of what you've tried.

Comment: Carrie, i'm not wanting code. I want explanations on what to do ...

Comment: We're here to *help*, not to do things for you.

Comment: you got it!  I want help :)   

So i added my code.   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of this would do the trick

```
while (scanner1.hasNextLine() && (scanner2.hasNextLine()){

    Strint line1 = scanner1.nextLine();
    String line2 = scanner2.nextLine();

    // parse line1
    String[] line1Tokens = lineS1,split(",");

    // parse line2
    String[] line2Tokens = line2.split(",");

    // Print
    String ticket = line1Tokens[0];
    String arrived1 = line1Tokens[2];
    String arraved2 = line1Tokens[3];

    String pickup1 = line2Tokens[1];
    String pickup2 = line2Tokens[2];

    System.out.println("Ticket: " + ticket + ", " + 
                       "Arrived: " + arrived1 + ":" + arived2 + " --- " + 
                       "Pickup: " + pickup1 + ":" + pickup2 + " --- " + 
                       "Cost: ");
}

printWriter.close();
```

This is assuming all the file lines match up accordingly

**Edit: using a method**

```
public static void merge(File file1, File file2) throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(file1);
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(file2);

    while (scanner1.hasNextLine() && (scanner2.hasNextLine()){

        Strint line1 = scanner1.nextLine();
        String line2 = scanner2.nextLine();

        // parse line1
        String[] line1Tokens = lineS1,split(",");

        // parse line2
        String[] line2Tokens = line2.split(",");

        // Print
        String ticket = line1Tokens[0];
        String arrived1 = line1Tokens[2];
        String arraved2 = line1Tokens[3];

        String pickup1 = line2Tokens[1];
        String pickup2 = line2Tokens[2];

        System.out.println("Ticket: " + ticket + ", " + 
                           "Arrived: " + arrived1 + ":" + arived2 + " --- " + 
                           "Pickup: " + pickup1 + ":" + pickup2 + " --- " + 
                           "Cost: ");

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    File file2 = new File("someText1.txt");
    File file1 = new File("someText1.txt");

    merge(file1, file2);

}
```

**Edit: If you don't want the `merge()` method to print, instead return a String**

You can have your method return a `String` instead of it printing

```
 public String merge(File file1, File file2) throws IOException {

      String entirePrint = "";

      while (scanner1.hasNextLine() && (scanner2.hasNextLine()){

          // other code      

          String oneLine = "Ticket: " + ticket + ", " + 
                           "Arrived: " + arrived1 + ":" + arived2 + " --- " + 
                           "Pickup: " + pickup1 + ":" + pickup2 + " --- " + 
                           "Cost: " + "/n";

          entirePrint += oneLine;

      }
      return entirePrint;
 }
```

`main`

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

      File file1 = 
      File file2 =

      YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();

      String print = yourClass.merge(file1, file2);

      System.out.println(print);
 }
```

Comment: But I'm using one method for both files, and I just want to

System.out.println(MergedFiles)

Comment: See my edit. If you want the method to a return `String` so that you can do just this  `System.out.println(merge)`, then have the method signature return a `String`; leave out the two parameters I have in the method signature; in the `sb` append a `"\n"` to the end of each line; finally have the method return `sb.toString()`. Then you can just call the method with not args `(System.out.println(mergre());` If you don't know what all these things mean, then I don't know what else I can do. I'm not going to do the entire problem for you. This is just a general outline

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XJiE2QJe  that is my merge method.  It won't work correctly however.  I'm using an entire file altogether specifically for my main as well... here's my main --- http://pastebin.com/9494JL9f

Comment: Don't expect people on this site to look at cod on an external link. Why don't you post what you have as an edit.

Comment: could you see now if you can't take a look and revise it?

Comment: First of all, `sb` is not a `String`, it's a `StringBuilder`. Two totally different things.  So you can't do this `if(sb.charAt(0) >= 48 && sb.charAt(0) <= 57)` or this `sb.length()`.  That won't even compile.

Comment: And why are you calling `scanner1.nextLine()` twice `String line = scanner1.nextLine();
        String line1 = scanner1.nextLine();`?

Comment: i've never used a stringbuilder.  In fact, he hasn't taught us that at all... I'm actually learning what it is now, though.  What should I replace my parse code with?

Comment: @Blood Fox, check out my edit. Maybe you can pick up something from that. The method works fine. In the edit, I don't use a `StringBuilder` anymore. might be easier for you to read.

Comment: Oh my gosh!  It works!  BUT, it throws an error, probably because the teacher ALSO wants us to parse the white space AFTER all the text.  can't i use a trim() somewhere?

Comment: I edited the original document to post the error and what I currently have!

Comment: So, the file didn't fully print, is that what happened? Also, Did you add any extra code to the `merge method()`? Honestly it really makes no sense to me why that method is throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  The only thing I can think is that maybe somewhere in the text file, the format is different after the line `Ticket: 1433`

Comment: WOW - That part was rediculous.   Okay, so I looped "trash" every time.  I put that back outside the while loop, to get rid of the FIRST line in each file.   Now the only problem is the white space and carriage returns in the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would write Java code to a single pass read of both files.  I assume you know how to write a Java program and you know what a merge sort is and I suggest you try putting these together. On reflection you don't need a merge sort, you can just read the data in the order it appears and build / add the information into a data structure like.

```
final Map<Integer, MyRecord> map = new HashMap<>();

public MyRecord acquireRecord(int ticket) {
  MyRecord rec = map.get(ticket);
  if (rec == null)
      map.put(ticket, rec = new MyRecord(ticket));
  return rec;
}
```

where MyRecord records all the information about a ticket number.

When you run into trouble, use a debugger first, and if that doesn't help post the code you have and a specific question about it.

Comment: @SamIam I partially disagree. I would add some details, however.

Comment: Currently, I'm using two methods, so I'm pretty sure I can't mergeSort,  or haven't learned it yet at least....

Comment: @BIoodFox It might reduce the memory consumption if you could output the data as you read it, but there doesn't appear to be a need and it would add complexity.